# Load XML string from Column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, xml-parsing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file in which one of the columns is an XML string.

I tried extracting this field and writing to a file in the first step and reading the file in the next step. But each row has an XML header tag. So the resulting file is not a valid XML file.

How can I use the PySpark XML parser ('com.databricks.spark.xml') to read this string and parse out the values?

The following doesn't work:

```
tr = spark.read.json( "my-file-path")
trans_xml = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='book').load(tr.select("trans_xml"))
```

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 1):

Try Hive XPath UDFs ([LanguageManual XPathUDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF)):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
>>> df.select(expr("xpath({0}, '{1}')".format(column_name, xpath_expression)))
```

or Python UDF:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> schema = ... # Define schema
>>> def parse(s):
...     root = ET.fromstring(s)
        result = ... # Select values
...     return result
>>> df.select(udf(parse, schema)(xml_column))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try the UDF approach and update how it went. I don't think XPath will work for my case as the data is nested in multiple layers.

Comment: What would the schema look like for example?

Comment: Thank you.  An example of the schema and value selection here would be immensely helpful.